# Knife deaths by country per year

Tags: data-request

I am trying to find the number of knife deaths and/or knife attacks by country per year.  There are many sources for gun deaths, but strangely not any that I could find for knife deaths.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can download crime/murder statistics that are classified by "mechanism" from the [United Nations Office on Drugs and Crime](https://www.unodc.org/).

- [Data portal](https://data.unodc.org/)
- On the left menu sidebar, choose "Crime and Criminal Justice"
- Then select "Homicide"
- Then select "Percent of homicides by mechanism (2005-2012)
- Create an XLS export (here's a [direct link](https://stats.unodc.org/webcontent/dcm.uploads/downloads/GHS2013_Mechanism.xlsx))
- The term they seem to use is "Sharp" for knife deaths
- Note that there are some other potential categories, so you may find better data sets by digging around.